# How to assign buttons using for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, button, assign

Can you help me?

I am still trying to understand how to assign `listType` to a button.

There are 8 buttons.

Each of these would be assigned to a specific button.

I am stuck on how to do this.

https://jsfiddle.net/82gv4nhm/

Doing this only assigns `playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g"` to a specific button.

This means   i - 0 playlist is being assigned as the first button.

How would I then assign `listType` to a specific button?

```
  let playerVarsList = [{
      playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g"
    },
    {
      listType: "playlist",
      list: "PLYeOyMz9C9kYmnPHfw5-ItOxYBiMG4amq"
    },
    {}
  ];

  for (let i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    players.add(".playSingle" + i, {
      playerVars: playerVarsList[i - 0]
    });
  }
```

This `i - 0` inside here: `playerVars: playerVarsList[i - 0]` tells the `playlist` what number button it is:

```
playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g

players.add(".playSingle" + i, {
playerVars: playerVarsList[i - 1]
});
```

For this one, what tells it what button number it should be?

```
listType: "playlist",
list: "PLYeOyMz9C9kYmnPHfw5-ItOxYBiMG4amq"
}
```

How the code works is, after clicking on a button a video appears.

```
  <button class="playSingle0 cover" type="button" data-container="play1" data-id="M7lc1UVf-VE"></button>
  <button class="playSingle1 cover" type="button" data-container="play1" data-id="M7lc1UVf-VE"></button>
  <button class="playSingle2 cover" type="button" data-container="play1" data-id="M7lc1UVf-VE"></button>
  <button class="playSingle3 cover" type="button" data-container="play1" data-id="M7lc1UVf-VE"></button>
  <button class="playSingle4 cover" type="button" data-container="play1" data-id="M7lc1UVf-VE"></button>
  <button class="playSingle5 cover" type="button" data-container="play1" data-id="M7lc1UVf-VE"></button>
  <button class="playSingle6 cover" type="button" data-container="play1" data-id="M7lc1UVf-VE"></button>
  <button class="playSingle7 cover" type="button" data-container="play1" data-id="M7lc1UVf-VE"></button>
```

I am having trouble understanding how to do it.

To do this more than one of these would be needed: `i - 0`

```
playerVars: playerVarsList[i - 0],

playerVars: playerVarsList[i - 3]
```

**or**

`playerVars: playerVarsList[i - 0, i - 3]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Assigning values using an Array

Let's start with explaining the loop and how this uses an array of objects to assign player parameters to each button.

```
let playerVarsList = [{
    playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g"
  },
  {
    listType: "playlist",
    list: "PLYeOyMz9C9kYmnPHfw5-ItOxYBiMG4amq"
  },
  {}
]

for (let i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
  players.add(".playSingle" + i, {
    playerVars: playerVarsList[i]
  })
}
```

This contains an array of objects called `playerVarsList` (*this specific example only has 3 indexes, so for all 8 buttons you would need to add additional objects, which I'll cover later*).

So the value for the `playSingle0` button will be `{ playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g" }`.
And the value for `playSingle1` will be `{ listType: "playlist", list: "PLYeOyMz9C9kYmnPHfw5-ItOxYBiMG4amq" }`.
Lastly, the value for `playSingle2` will be `{}`

So using this array of objects, if you want to set the value for the 7th button, you would need your `playerVarsList` to look something like this:

```
let playerVarsList = [
  { playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g" }, // This is the first button
  {
    listType: "playlist",
    list: "PLYeOyMz9C9kYmnPHfw5-ItOxYBiMG4amq"
  }, //  This is the second button
  {}, // This is the third button
  {}, // This is the fourth button
  {}, // This is the fifth button
  {}, // This is the sixth button
  {
    playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g",
    start: 300
  }, // This is the 7th button
  { start: 150, end: 1800 } // This is the eighth button
]
```

Also notice that I am not using `[i - 0]` as this isn't necessary. `i` or the current index of the loop will directly match a value in the `playerVarsList` so you don't need to preform any calculations on it.

Just as `".playSingle" + i` will give you `.playSingle0` for the first button, using `playerVarsList[i]` will translate to `playerVarsList[0]`, which is the first object in the array of `playerVarsList`.

This means this loop will go through all values in the `playerVarsList` and will set the player parameters one at a time, using the index that coorelates with the current index in the loop (*so index 0 uses the first object in the array, index 1 uses the second object, etc.*)

### Using the `forEach()` Loop

An alternative way to do this loop (*that is often easier to work with*) is the `.forEach()` method of looping.

When you use a standard `for()` loop, you need to declare a variable, set a condition, and the increment value. Then it loops through until the condition is false. A `.forEach()` loop lets you take an existing array and loop through all values, without needing to do things like declare an index or set a condition. Once all values have been looped through, it will end.

This means you would change your code to look something like this:

```
let playerVarsList = [
  { playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g" }, // This is the first button
  {
    listType: "playlist",
    list: "PLYeOyMz9C9kYmnPHfw5-ItOxYBiMG4amq"
  }, //  This is the second button
  {}, // This is the third button
  {}, // This is the fourth button
  {}, // This is the fifth button
  {}, // This is the sixth button
  {
    playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g",
    start: 300
  }, // This is the 7th button
  { start: 150, end: 1800 } // This is the eighth button
]

playerVarsList.forEach((pvl, i) => {
  players.add(`.playSingle${i}`, {
    playerVars: pvl
  })
}
```

In this, we are using 2 parameters in the `.forEach()` loop, `pvl` and `i`. The `pvl` value will be whatever the current value of our `playerVarsList` is. So for the first loop, `pvl` is the same as `playerVarsList[0]` in our old loop. The second parameter `i` is the same as a standard loop being that it is the index. We use this so we can get the correct button.

Another change you may notice is `.playSingle${i}` instead of `".playSingle" + i`. This is called a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in which you can wrap a string in backticks (*the little character to the left of the `1` key on most keyboads*). Then you no longer need to concatenate strings with variables by using the `+` operator. You can simply wrap any variable in `${}` instead and everything will be concatenated automatically.

Comment: Do I have this set up right?  for (let i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    players.add(".playSingle" + i, {
      playerVars: playerVarsList[i]
    })
  }   /// Does that look good to you?

Comment: @MarySmithJames In this case beacuse there are 8 buttons you would not want `i <= 7`. Because `i` starts at 0, you want it to stop right at 7, and using `i <= 7` means that it will still increase 1 last time when `i` is equal to 7. Just remove the equals sign and it looks right: `for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) { players.add(".playSingle" + i, { playerVars: playerVarsList[i] }) }`

Comment: Button 8 video is not appearing on the screen now? After I added that. https://jsfiddle.net/w9csvu80/

Comment: @MarySmithJames That's my mistake, you had it correct the first time (using the `<=` operator). Normally I do `for` loops like `for(let i = 0; i < 8; i++)` but because you used 7 (the last index for the buttons), using `<=` was correct. This is also another reason I prefer the `.forEach()` loop as it will always loop through all values and you don't need to tell it when to stop.

Comment: If I want to add/assign start to a button, how would I do that in the code? https://jsfiddle.net/rxonm4py/

  players.add(".playStart", {
    playerVars: {
      start: 300,
    }
  });

Comment: Adding start or end tells the video where in the video to begin playing or stop.

Comment: @MarySmithJames I updated my answer to better show this, but basically the `playerVarsList` just holds the `playerVars` for each button, and so if you need to add an additional parameter for a specific button, you can just add it inside of the object (*inside of the `{}` curly brackets*). If there are already parameters, just make sure you separate each one with a comma. In my answer the 7th and 8th buttons are using the `start` parameter, but of course you can place that in any of the buttons.

Comment: If I wanted to add an id to this part, how would I do that in the code?

  players.add(".playStart", {
  videoId: '0dgNc5S8cLI',
    playerVars: {
      start: 300,
    }
  });

You can see it working here in the other code as the last button. https://jsfiddle.net/cy2urvne/

Comment: I got stuck trying to figure out how to do that. You can see it is working in the other code.

Comment: This was my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/je53p2m4/     {
    videoId: '0dgNc5S8cLI',
    }, // This is the sixth button /// No video is showing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250246/discussion-between-essxtee-and-mary-smith-james).

Comment: If the for Loop gets changed to this:

for (let i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
     players.add(".playSingle" + i, playerVarsList[i]);
   }

What would the forEach one become then?

What would it get changed to?

 playerVarsList.forEach((pvl, i) => {
    players.add(".playSingle" + i, {
      playerVars: pvl
    });
 });