# How would this for loop code be adjusted so that .playSingle2 video is able to be viewed on the screen? Without having to add an extra button

Tags: javascript, for-loop

To reproduce, click on the red exit button, then on the 2nd button.

https://jsfiddle.net/2q7yknrv/1/

You will see no video is appearing.

How would the `for loop` code be adjusted to allow for `.playSingle2` video to appear?

How exactly would this be done in the code?

Would I be able to tell it to skip over it?

You do see it is not appearing on the screen, right?

[image]

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

  let playlists = Array(3);

  playlists[1] = "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g";
  for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    let playvars = {}
    if (playlists[i]) {
      playvars.playerVars = {
        playlist: playlists[i]
      };
    }
    players.add(".playSingle" + i, playvars);
  }

  players.add(".playSingle2",  {
    playerVars: {
      listType: "playlist",
      list: "PLYeOyMz9C9kYmnPHfw5-ItOxYBiMG4amq"
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The [playlist parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#playlist) only accepts a comma seperated list of video IDs, so the array and `for` loop do not make sense. Additionally, the `listType` and `list` parameters are to load an existing YouTube playlist, rather than create a playlist on-the-fly by specifying a list of video IDs. Basically you are using 2 separate API functions that are not supported together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Debugging Code

This question is a good example as to why learning how to debug your own code is critical to solving issues.

Let's start with what can be done to debug. OP provided two links (*which are not [minimal, reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)*)

- Working: https://jsfiddle.net/4x6e3am5/
- Not working: https://jsfiddle.net/2q7yknrv/1/

To debug I first took the two examples and did a simple text comparison (tools like DiffChecker are useful for this). This showed me what changed. And there were a couple of changes that stood out so the next thing I did was add some `console.log()` lines to follow the code as it attempted to add a player. This revealed that the `playerOptions` parameter being passed was empty, meaning the playlist information was never passed.

Upon digging further I noticed an important change. The one that does work changed this line in the `for` loop:

```
players.add(".playSingle1" + i, playvars);
```

to this:

```
players.add(".playSingle" + i, playvars);
```

***Why is this significant?*** Because in the first example, while looping it will try to add a player to the classes `playSingle11`, `playSingle12`, and `playSingle13`, none of which exist on the page. This means the loop does nothing as the elements it's trying to use don't exist and the rest of the code will execute as intended.

In the second example (*which does not work*), it will try to add a player for `playSingle1`, `playSingle2`, and `playSingle3`. What's important is `playSingle2` gets called twice (once in the loop and again later in the same function). This creates your issue because you are calling `playSingle2` twice. And so when you change the last call outside of the loop to a class called `works`, it *seems* to fix the issue because you are not calling `playSingle2` twice anymore.

### Evidence

This can be verified a few different ways.

The easiest is the remove your `for` loop entirely. You'll notice that the `playSingle2` playlist loads as intended. You don't need the `works` class to make it work, as the `for` loop is causing the issue.

Another way is to use another class like `playSingle4`, as this class isn't called in your loop. It's not that a random class like `works` is really a fix but instead, your loop and the code outside of your loop is calling the same class creating an issue.

### Issues With Player API Playlist

Let's first look at the `for` loop provided and step through it to understand what is wrong with it.

```
let playlists = Array(3);

playlists[1] = "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g";
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  let playvars = {}
  if (playlists[i]) {
    playvars.playerVars = {
      playlist: playlists[i]
    };
  }
  players.add(".playSingle" + i, playvars);
}
```

First, it declares an array called `playlists` with 3 empty/undefined values.
Next, it sets the second index (*as arrays start at a 0 index*) to a string that is comma separated.

This means the array actually looks like this when we start the loop:

```
[undefined, '0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g', undefined]
```

Then, this `for` loop does 3 passes, each time taking an index from the `playlists` array and storing a value in a variable, then passing this to the `add()` method to add a player.

But, the issue is the array still has 2 empty/undefined values.

So the first and third players receive an empty playlist, while the second player gets initialized twice.

My assumption is you are trying to load both a preset playlist and a custom ***'on-the-fly'*** playlist (a list of video IDs), which is not supported by the YouTube IFrame Player API.

The `list` and `listType` parameter will always take precedence over the `playlist` parameter if both are present.

- [Example 1](https://jsfiddle.net/EssXTee/74ok6Ltf/1/): `list` and `listType` are declared first
- [Example 2](https://jsfiddle.net/EssXTee/jm175eoz/): `playlist` is declared first

Both examples load the YouTube playlist, rather than the custom list of video IDs.

### [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct)

Stack Overflow is a question and answer site that is populated with volunteers. This means that when you have a question, you should be respectful of those trying to help. Many people here are taking time out of their day to provide help/knowledge/insight as well as solutions to problems.

If someone offers information that can help, do not harass or berate them. Almost always, that information was shared with the intention of helping solve the problem. If you need clarity, feel free to ask but remember users here are not paid and are helping when they have the availability to do so. Sometimes responses and answers can take time so always be patient.

Comment: Thank you and appreciated.

Comment: In the code that works, the button was changed to a different name, so the array just skips over it:  <button class="works cover" type="button" data-container="play1" ></button>  ///// players.add(".works",  { Which is the reason why it works in the code.

Comment: @MarySmithJames My apologies as I got the two examples mixed up in my explaination, but I have updated my post to explain this properly now. You are calling `add()` on the `playSingle2` class twice, which causes it to fail. I also added two jsfiddles to show why you can't use both a YouTube playlist and a list of Video IDs on the same player. Also, in both examples you will see I am not using your `works` class but the playlists still load (because again the issue was with initializing the same player twice)

Comment: And just to be a little more comprehensive, [here is another jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/EssXTee/79gzqv6e/) that uses a loop to initialize the players. This example again does not use the `works` class but instead the standard **playSingle1**, **playSingle2**, and **playSingle3** classes (*because each player is only initialized once*).

Comment: Would you be able to help me figure out how to do this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74700021/how-to-assign-buttons-using-for-loop I am having a very hard time trying to figure out how to do that in the code.